# How to grab all files of FTP server?

Tags: ftp, ftp-server

The condition is my college has a ftp server where my lecture slides and other files are kept. I have to download each file by right clicking it and 'save as'. I tried using utility software to download folders from ftp server or keeping the address of ftp server to my windows explorer. But none worked.
Any option included above doesnt work because our ftp server is accessed through a fserver.collegename.com which is a http based login page.
How can I design a software to access the ftp server? or any idea by which i can download folder or multiple files at once?

Comment: If all that they are providing is a Http connection, then it is not a ftp server but a http server.  If you have ftp access then there are many tools to access it, but if this port is not open then you can not use them.

Comment: Please ask your college IT staff, does it really use ftp service or just http service to share the files. Because they have different behaviour and different solution.